# Show that two definitions of $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ on wikipedia are equivalent

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I want to prove that the two definitions of $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ are equivalent.

Article in question : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Essentially i want to prove that for a sequence $(a_n)_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ whose set of all limit points is $E$, that this equation works
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{m\ge n}a_m = \sup E$$

Comment: Just observe that $y_m=\sup_{m\geq n}x_m$ is an decreasing (as in non-increasing) sequence, so its limit and infimum are the same. It is decreasing because as $m$ grows there are less elements to take the supremum from.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m\ge n}a_m.$ Let $b_n=\sup_{m\ge n}a_m.$

(1).If $B\in \Bbb R:$ The sequence $(b_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is decreasing (i.e. $n'>n\implies b_{n'}\le b_n)$ and converges to $B.$

Take any $\epsilon\in \Bbb R^+.$ Take $ n_1$ such that $n\ge n_1\implies B+\epsilon> b_n.$ For any $n\ge n_1$ there exists $n'\ge  n$ such that $a_{n'}>b_n-\epsilon$ by def' of $b_n.$ And if $n'\ge n$ then $a_{n'}\le b_n,$ also by def'n of $b_n.$ And $B+\epsilon > b_{n'}$ if $n'\ge n\ge n_1.$ So we have $$B+\epsilon  \ge b_{n'}\ge a_{n'}>b_n-\epsilon\ge B-\epsilon.$$ And $n'\ge n,$ with no upper bound on $n.$

So for any $\epsilon >0$ the set $\{n'\in \Bbb N: |a_{n'}-B|<\epsilon\}$ is not empty and has no upper bound in $\Bbb N$. So there exists a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converging to $B.$

Suppose $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ had a subsequence converging to $C>B.$ Take $r\in \Bbb R^+$ such that $B<B+r<C.$  Then there are infinitely many $m$ such that  $a_m>B+r.$ But then $ b_n\ge B+r$  for every $n$ (by the def'n of $b_n)$ implying $B= \lim_{n\to \infty}b_n\ge B+r>B,$ which is absurd.

Note: We allow the possibility $C=\infty,$ with the usual convention that "$(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $\infty$" means that for each $r\in \Bbb R,$ the set $\{n\in \Bbb N: x_n\le r\}$ is finite (i.e. bounded above in $\Bbb N)$.

(2). If $B=\infty:$ Then $\sup_n a_n=b_1=\infty.$ Because  $b_n\le b_1$ for all $n\in \Bbb N,$ so if $b_1 <\infty$  then $B=\lim_{ n\to \infty}b_n\le b_1<\infty.$

So $\{a_n: n\in \Bbb N\}$ is unbounded above in $\Bbb R$, so $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ has a subsequence converging to $\infty.$ It can't have a subsequence converging to $more$ than $\infty.$